# Laravel passport access and refresh token encoding from front end JS webapp

Tags: angular, security, frontend, laravel-passport, laravel-5.6

We have developed and published an Angular and Laravel based webapp. It completely runs over HTTPS and authentication is done using passport.

When the application receives the successful access token post authentication, we store the token in session storage and encode it using crypro-js. So no body can use the token and send further requests using other tools because this is encoded. But when we send other requests, we have to decode it and send as plain text in Bearer headers.

The problem is, anyone can see the token in that case and use it via any other tools like postman to obtain refresh token or can consume other services.

Is there a way to avoid this, any security measurements we missed? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with same approach in (laravel 5.6 + angular 5) just i'm also use refresh token

So for more security refresh your access token periodically

in my case (angular 5) i'm using setinterval function for refresh my token every 5 minutes (18000 ms)

`setInterval(MyFuncRefreshToken(), 18000);`